# GitHub managing multiple websites

Tags: github, shopify

I am wondering if anyone has a decent tutorial for my GitHub scenario. I want to be able to manage and sync changes to certain files in a Shopify theme across multiple stores while keeping others (which handle things like localisation) as is. I'm new to GitHub and keen to learn so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect your github theme to a store. You get to pick a branch. So make each store a branch. Now you can edit your theme, push changes to a specific branch and then that store assigned to the theme and branch will pick up those changes.